# Remove irregular edge in Sentinel image

Tags: raster, r, sentinel-2

I have [2 Sentinel files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m4dueviquqog7ip/AAAVYo3A-247vLgoCaoEHjPBa?dl=0) that I join in R:

```
library(raster)
y = raster("./L1C_T36MZE_A016248_20180802T075248.tif")
z = raster("./L1C_T36MZE_A016291_20180805T080721.tif")

ss = raster::merge(y,z)
plot(ss)
```

This gives a file with a seam (the diagonal line) where the images have spurious edge values.

[image]

What is the best way to deal these values? 
I have tried:

```
sp = click(a, xy = T)
spp = spPolygons(as.matrix(sp)[, 1:2])
plot(crop(a, spp))
```

but this did not help.

Comment: The values along the seem do not look like NA's but rather spurious edge values. The merge function does not do anything to create concurrence along edges and assigns edge values based on order of input. So, change the order of input or clip out the edge values so you have clean edges to merge.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the order of input did not help. How do I clip the edge values? The "seam" runs diagonal.

Comment: unless there are specific values along the edge that you can turn into NA's you really have no choice but to create a polygon or raster mask that defines the area(s) that you want to keep and then use the raster::mask function to "clip" your rasters.

Comment: If you plot each one separately you can see that they overlap by a long way, and what you see in your plot is the ragged edge of one raster. The ragged edge of the other raster is way off to the right.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question (and title). I am not successful in removing the edge values...

Comment: i would try loading the rasters in QGIS or ArcMap and use a pixel inspector to inspect the edge cases.Also, which bands do you select for visualization?

Comment: I have no experience with QGIS or ArcMap, but was able to look at the edge cases using `raster::click`. I have tried to `reclassify`, but this didn't help much as it affected other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a mosaic operation rather than merge. This will allow you to have control over the overlapping regions. The [`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package has a `mosaic` operation where you can define the overlap function (e.g. min, max, mean, etc). For example:

```
mosaic(image1, image2, fun = max)
```

[NCEAS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) has an interesting article on how to create a raster mosaic that may be useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The images overlap.

Both scenes have weird looking pixels at their diagonal side.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems that the edge pixel do not contain valid information and should be removed:

[image]

Changing the order will not solve your issue. Where did you obtain the images?

If I search for your scenes in the [EO browser](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/?lat=-0.4123&lng=36.2391&zoom=11&time=2018-08-05&preset=1_TRUE_COLOR&datasource=Sentinel-2%20L1C) I don't get the weird diagonal spurious pixels. I would try to download clear images without the weird edges.

Comment: The fix is to create a polygon that runs down between the edges along the middle of the seam (annoyingly a vertical line won't work) then mask one raster and inverse-mask the other raster, then merge them.

Comment: thanks! The images are from [Earth Explorer, Sentinel](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), files L1C_T36MZE_A016248_20180802T075248 and L1C_T36MZE_A016291_20180805T080721. The solution of @Aaron worked for me. Strangely enough the files have different values for water, so I will have to reclassify as well.

Comment: that is great to hear. Be careful though with creating a mosaic when your input data contains unmasked spurious data. What if the edge pixels have a higher "max" value than the correct pixel in the other image? You definitely want to create a mosaic but only when the input data is correct.